# SOAP PHP Client returns missing params but soapUI works fine

Tags: php

I created the following php soap client and the service continues to report missing or invalid adminPassword, version. When I use soapUI the method and parameters passed works fine, so not sure why the php client not is working.

I'm also getting a Notice msg so not sure if that has anything to do w/ it "Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5 stdClass"

Response:
( [method] => getUsageReport_v1 [statusCode] => GEN006 [statusMessage] => The following required parameters are missing or invalid: adminPassword,version. [version] => 1.0 [monthlyReceiveReports] => [monthlySendReports] => [receiveReports] => [sendReports] => )

Client (masking adminId and adminPassword):

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.efaxcorporate.com/corp/services/CorpAdmin?wsdl");
$parm = array("adminId" => "*****","version" => "1.0", "adminPassword" => "***",);
print_r($client->getUsageReport_v1(array($parm)));
```

Thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 0):

I believe youre missing the username:

```
<wsdl:message name="getUsageReport_v1Request">
<wsdl:part name="adminId" type="xsd:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="adminUserName" type="xsd:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="adminPassword" type="xsd:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="version" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
```